# order of integration for triple integral

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

Calculate $$ \iiint\limits _{V}\left|y\right|e^{x^{2}}dV $$
Given $$ V=\left(x,y,z\right):\begin{cases}
0\le y\le1\\
y^{2}\le x\le1\\
x^{2}\le z\le1
\end{cases} $$
Obviously $|y|=y $ within our boundries.

Naturally we can't integrate this with the normal order because we can't find the anti derivative of $ e^{x^2}$.

My attempt involved:
$$ \begin{cases}
y^{4}\le x^{2}\le z\\
0\le y^{2}\le x\le1
\end{cases}\Rightarrow\begin{cases}
y^{4}\le z\le1\\
0\le y\le\sqrt{x}
\end{cases} $$

The ingegral then becomes: $$\int\limits _{0}^{1}dx\int\limits _{0}^{\sqrt{x}}dy\int\limits _{y^{4}}^{1}ye^{x^{2}}dz=\int\limits _{0}^{1}dx\int\limits _{0}^{\sqrt{x}}\left(y-y^{5}\right)e^{x^{2}}dy= \\
\int\limits _{0}^{1}\frac{x}{2}e^{x^{2}}-\frac{x^{3}}{6}e^{x^{2}}dx= \\
-\dfrac{\left(x^{2}-4\right)\mathrm{e}^{x^{2}}}{12}\biggl|_{0}^{1}=\frac{3e-4}{12} $$

How can I figure the right order of integration for a question, and the right limits?

Comment: Is the finial answer as it should be so far?

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have the final answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given the integrand, you can first integrate wrt $dy$ then $dx$ and finally $dz$. The bounds will be,

$0 \leq y \leq \sqrt x; 0 \leq x \leq \sqrt z; 0 \leq z \leq 1$

First thing to note is that at all points in the region $V$, $0 \leq x, y, z \leq 1$. For bounds of $y$, we see that $x \geq y^2  \implies y \leq \sqrt x$. Once we integrate wrt $dy$, we have a function of the form $c \cdot x ~e^{x^2}$. Now for bounds of $x$, $z \geq x^2 \implies x \leq \sqrt z$. So integrating wrt $dx$ next will give a function of the form $c \cdot (e^z - 1)$. That will lead to a straightforward integral with bounds of $z$ as $[0, 1]$.

The integral becomes,

$ \displaystyle \int_0^1 \int_0^{\sqrt z} \int_0^{\sqrt x} y \cdot e^{x^{2}} dy ~ dx ~ dz$

Comment: makes sense and the result seems to be pretty.
However,what makes the choices for bounds right here and not for example in the way I did it or Mikasa did it? both of the bounds seem right to me.

Comment: @DannyBlozrov as pretty as $(e-2)/4$? :) :)

Comment: @DannyBlozrov Are you asking what's wrong with bounds that you have chosen? I just want to make sure I get your question right before I answer.

Comment: Yes. Also doesn't your result give $ \frac{e-1}{4} $ in the end?

Comment: No the answer is what I wrote. In your work, there is a problem in the lower bound of $z$. There is no way to write the lower bound of $z$ as $y^4$. It is $x^2$

Comment: @DannyBlozrov please note $z = y^4$ only at the intersection curve of surface $z = x^2$ and $x = y^2$, not elsewhere on the surface.

Comment: I see, that makes sense. tyvm

Answer (score 2):

I see the given region $x\Big|_{y^2} ^1,~~y\Big|_0^1,~~z\Big|_{x^2}^1$ turns to $$x\Big|_{0} ^1,~~y\Big|_0^{\sqrt{x}},~~z\Big|_{x^2}^1$$

Comment: The integrals could be done simply by using integration by parts.

Comment: mind explaining how did you get the bounds for integration?